# i want to display working hours greater than 20

Tags: sql

```
select fname as 'Employee_Name',sum(hours) as 'Working hours'
from employee e join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn
group by ssn;
```

Comment: That's invalid (standard) SQL. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to filter the group result. To do so use **Havging** clause along with **Group by** clause.

Let's do this:

```
select fname as 'Employee Name',sum(hours) as 'Working hours'
from employee e join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn
group by ssn , fname Having sum(hours) > 20;
```

Also **notice** that column used in the select clause must be there in the Group By clause but the column in the Group By clause need not be there in the Select clause.

Comment: thanks i was trying the same but i was using -having Working hours >20 and it was showing error. with this got the result

Comment: cant i ask another question right now.

Comment: can i use any function operation in having clause.

Comment: Suppose i have table after grouping and want to display table contents only for minimum value of one particular column

Comment: Which project(s) have the least number of employees?
select pname as 'Project_Name' , count(ssn) as 'Employee_count'
from employee e join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn join project p on w.pno = p.pnumber
group by pname
having Employee_count = (select min(Employee_count));

Comment: come here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java